# Templating a directly raw query in a html table

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm beginner in django and i'm using a read-only db, I just wanna make some selects and show it as a table in my template, but I cant return coulmn by column into my html table, help me, 
I'm using a directky raw query

Model.py
    from django.db import connection

```
# Create your models here.
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    desc = cursor.description
    return [
        dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
]


def my_custom_sql(self):
    with connection.cursor()as cursor:
        cursor.execute("""
                       SELECT EQUIP_ID, LINE_CODE, PLANT_CODE 
                       FROM tbs_rm_mnt_shift_sumr 
                       where SUMR_YMD = '20180405' AND SIDE_CODE = 'T' AND 
                       rownum < 20
                       """ )
        row = dictfetchall(cursor)
        return row
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from .models import my_custom_sql


# Create your views here.

def show_list(request):
   query= my_custom_sql(self='my_custom_sql')
    return render(request,'monitoring.html', {'query': query})
```

monitoring.html

```
    <table border="2" style="solid black">
     <tr>
        <td>Equip</td>
        <td>Line</td>
        <td>Plant</td>

        {% for instance in query %}
            {% for field, value in instance.items %}

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ value }} </td>

                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
     </tr>
    </table>
```

browser output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzOms.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you are only outputting one `td` for each row.

```
{% for instance in query %}
  {% for field, value in instance.items %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ value }} </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It sounds like should loop inside the `tr` tag:

```
{% for instance in query %}
    <tr>
      {% for field, value in instance.items %}
      <td>{{ value }} </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

However, you can't assume the order of the keys in the dictionary, so you should either access the items by key, or rethink whether you want to use `dictfetchall`.

```
{% for instance in query %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ instance.EQUIP_ID }} </td>
      <td>{{ instance.LINE_ID }} </td>
      <td>{{ instance.PLANT_CODE }} </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you, this definetely fixed my problem,